# Ajax not working after add new posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#message').focus();
        $('#message').keypress(function(event) {

            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {
                var message = $('#message').val();
                var sender = $($sender).val();
                var reciver = $($reciver).val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "code.php",
                    data: {message: message, sender: sender, reciver: reciver},
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#result').append(status);
                        $('#message').val('');
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a little problem here when I add these line of code my "ENTER" is not working, but when I remove em, it is. What am I doing wrong?

```
sender: sender, reciver: reciver
var sender = $($sender).val();
var reciver = $($reciver).val();
```

By the way $sender and $reciver are GET functions

Comment: `sender: sender, reciver: reciver` is not valid JS code and would be causing a syntax error. Check the console for more detail

Comment: what is the error you are getting? check your browser console.

Comment: Sorry i aam not getting what are you trying to say should i rename em or

Comment: I am not getting error my enter starts working as new line not as posting button

Comment: It's hard to say as you've not shown what you're trying to do. The `sender: sender, reciver: reciver` line seems redundant and could be removed. Where do you define `$sender` and `$reciver`?

Comment: what do you mean by  "GET functions"?

Comment: Answer below helped .... <?php echo $sender;?>

Comment: Replace $($sender)  by $(<?php echo  $_GET['sender']; ?>) and $($reciver)  by $(<?php echo $_GET['reciver']; ?> )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#message').focus();
        $('#message').keypress(function(event) {

            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {
                var message = $('#message').val();
                var sender = '<?php echo $sender;?>';
                var reciver = '<?php echo $reciver;?>';
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "code.php",
                    data: {message: message, sender: sender, reciver: reciver},
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#result').append(status);
                        $('#message').val('');
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
```